# Alignment in sketch app

Tags: shapes, sketch-app, alignment

Is there is any option in sketch app where I can align object with reference object? E.g. I have on icon and one rectangle shape, want my icon center middle aligned of rectangle.

Like in illustrator we have option. Check image for reference. [image]

Answer (score 1):

To align two objects, select both layers and use the alignment icons to align them.

[image]

You can also use this functionality to center an object (or multiple) within an artboard.